# Richfaces 4 + JBoss 6 = Exception on deploy

Tags: java, exception, jsf, jboss, richfaces

I develop a web application for JBoss 6.x based on JSF 2.0 and Richfaces 4. After I deploy my application on the server the following exception is thrown:

```
22:52:31,669 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] Unable to process annotations for url, vfs:/opt/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/admin-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  Reason: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

22:52:31,670 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] : java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:67) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:214) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:198) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:50) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:71) [:1.6.0_26]
    at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClasspath(AnnotationScanner.java:298) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(AnnotationScanner.java:217) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(JBossAnnotationProvider.java:123) [:1.0.3]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:762) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:733) [:2.0.3-]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [:1.6.0_26]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:326) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:220) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossMojarraConfigureListener.contextInitialized(JBossMojarraConfigureListener.java:58) [:1.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_26]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at $Proxy41.start(Unknown Source)   at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_26]
```

And then immediately another one:

```
22:52:31,714 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] Unable to process annotations for url, vfs:/opt/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/deploy/admin-console.war/WEB-INF/lib/richfaces-core-impl-4.1.0.Final.jar/META-INF/faces-config.xml.  Reason: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

22:52:31,715 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] : java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:127) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:135) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.<init>(URLJarFile.java:67) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile$1.run(URLJarFile.java:214) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:198) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:50) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:70) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:104) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:71) [:1.6.0_26]
    at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.processClasspath(AnnotationScanner.java:298) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner.getAnnotatedClasses(AnnotationScanner.java:217) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossAnnotationProvider.getAnnotatedClasses(JBossAnnotationProvider.java:123) [:1.0.3]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:762) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager$AnnotationScanTask.call(ConfigManager.java:733) [:2.0.3-]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [:1.6.0_26]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:326) [:2.0.3-]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:220) [:2.0.3-]
    at org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossMojarraConfigureListener.contextInitialized(JBossMojarraConfigureListener.java:58) [:1.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3369) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3828) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:294) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:476) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:95) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_26]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at $Proxy41.start(Unknown Source)   at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:53) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:41) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:301) [:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:671) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:443) [:6.1.0.Final (Build SVNTag:JBoss_6.1.0.Final date: 20110816)]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:189) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:102) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:49) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:63) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:55) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:179) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1832) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1550) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1571) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1491) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:939) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:654) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.change(DeployersImpl.java:1983) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:1076) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:679) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.deployers.MainDeployerPlugin.process(MainDeployerPlugin.java:106) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.dependency.ProfileControllerContext$DelegateDeployer.process(ProfileControllerContext.java:143) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.deploy(HDScanner.java:240) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner$HDScanAction.complete(HDScanner.java:192) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.TwoPCActionWrapper.doComplete(TwoPCActionWrapper.java:57) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.complete(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:74) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.actions.AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.prepare(AbstractTwoPhaseModificationAction.java:95) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.ModificationSession.prepare(ModificationSession.java:87) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.internalPerfom(AbstractActionController.java:234) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.performWrite(AbstractActionController.java:213) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:150) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.management.AbstractActionController.perform(AbstractActionController.java:135) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.scan(HDScanner.java:146) [:0.2.2]
    at org.jboss.profileservice.deployment.hotdeploy.HDScanner.run(HDScanner.java:90) [:0.2.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:204) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_26]
```

This exceptions don't affect on application work. At least I did not notice that.

Yet these I'm very concerned about these exceptions.

It seems that there is the conflict with the configuration files of JBoss and Richfaces. But I do not fully understand how I can fix it.

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: give a try to the 6.0.0.M4 version and above of jboss... https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its seems like a bug in Jboss server : [Jboss 6, JSF 2 and AJAX question](https://community.jboss.org/thread/152451)

you should upgrade the server to at least 6.0.0.M4 version

here is the bug report ticket [Bug report ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8024)

**Update :**

look at this ref' [Upgrade JBoss AS to JSF2](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UpgradeJBossASToJSF2) , the first link (that i posted above) says that if you upgrade your JBoss AS to JSF2 this issues should be resolved...

Comment: With JBoss 7 all works perfect. But required that application should works with version 6.1.

Comment: How this can help? Final release of JBoss 6.1 uses JSF2 by default. It has no need in update.

Comment: [This blog article](http://flaviocysne.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/unable-to-process-annotations-for-url.html) has another solution.